# JAVASCRIPT , HTML enabling input field based on radio button choice

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to have two input option enable based on the radio button choice, but only one option is enabling not matter which option I choose. Eg- If I choose sheetcake, instead of having input option for sheetcake, I have the input option of roundcake. I am new in javascript and any advice  will be much appreciated. Thank You. ( I tried to run the code in snippet and it works fine but I run the same code in browser and only one input box is working no matter what, I tried to run in 3 different browsers and got the same error, I don't know what is the issue and where I made a mistake. Thank You in advance.

```js
const sheetcake = document.getElementById("sheetcake");
const roundcake = document.getElementById("roundcake");
var caketype = document.getElementsById("caketype");

function CakeChoice(choice){
if (choice == sheetcake){
    document.getElementById("SheetLength").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("SheetWidth").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("RoundRadius").disabled=true;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("SheetLength").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("SheetWidth").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("RoundRadius").disabled=false;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="caketype">   
                    <label class="caketype required">Cake Type:</label> <br>
                    <input type="radio" id="sheetcake" name="caketype" value="0" required onclick="CakeChoice(sheetcake)">
                    <label>Sheet Cake</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="roundcake" name="caketype" value="0" required onclick="CakeChoice(roundcake)">
                    <label>Round Cake</label>
                    </div> 
                    <br>

                   
                    <div id="CakeDimensions" >
                        <label>Cake size (cm)</label><br>
                        <input type="number" id="SheetLength" value="0" min="30" max="60" required disabled>
                        <label class="form-label required">cm Length</label><br>
                        <input type="number" id="SheetWidth" value="0" min="30" max="45" required disabled>
                        <label class="form-label required">cm Width</label>
                    </div>                   
                    <br>
                   
                    <div id="round">
                    <label>Cake size</label><br>
                    <input type="number" id="RoundRadius" min="15" max="30"  disabled required>
                    <label class="form-label required">cm Radius</label>
                    </div>                   
                    <br><br>

                    <div id="cakelayers">
                        <label class="form-label required">How many layers?</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="OneLayer" name="CakeLayers" value="1layer" required>
                        <label for="OneLayer">One Layer</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="TwoLayers" name="CakeLayers" value="2layers" required>
                        <label for="TwoLayers">Two Layers</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" id="ThreeLayers" name="CakeLayers" value="3layers" required>
                        <label for="ThreeLayers">Three Layers</label>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
```

Comment: *w3schools issue*. You should never use `on*` handlers. Use [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. JS should be in one place only and that's its respective tag or file. `onclick="CakeChoice(sheetcake)"` what is `sheetcake` ? A varible? No, seems like you want a String: `onclick="CakeChoice(\"sheetcake\")"`, but as I said. Don't just use this. It's wrong from so many perspectives.

Comment: Another issue is that `if (choice == sheetcake){`  `sheetcake` is an Element, not a String

Comment: Another issue, `document.getElementsById` please, open Console in Developer Tools in your favorite browser. Should be `getElementById` - Singular.

Comment: I'm new to JS and not really sure how to use that properly. So instead of onclick, I should use that eventlistener right?

Comment: Another issue, makes no sense to have **two** `name="caketype" value="0"` Elements with the same attributes name and value

Comment: If you fix `caketype = document.getElementsById` removing the `s` to `caketype = document.getElementById`, your code will work, but you should improve it

Comment: no It doesn't , only one input is working and its in reverse order

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a slightly alternative approach which avoids having irrelevant disabled options that some users might be trying to activate.

Instead of disabling the irrelevant options, manipulating the display styles of the two sets of option for cake dimensions (by javascript) allows for only the relevant one to be available for interaction. This lets you make the relevant size option only appear when a type has been chosen (and toggles between them if the user changes their mind).

As you have fairly complex markup for each option, I've added extra divisions containing each group. The `id`s for the relevant divisions, `rectangle` and `round` are used to create references to each grouping in the javascript allowing access to their `style.display` property, which can be toggled.

```js
const sheetcake = document.getElementById("rectangle");
const roundcake = document.getElementById("round");
sheetcake.style = "display: none";
round.style = "display: none";


function CakeChoice(choice){
  if (choice == 'sheetcake'){
    sheetcake.style = "display: block";
    roundcake.style = "display: none";
  } else {
    sheetcake.style = "display: none";
    roundcake.style = "display: block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="caketype">   
  <label class="caketype required">Cake Type:</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" id="sheetcake" name="caketype" value="0" required onclick="CakeChoice('sheetcake')">
  <label>Sheet Cake</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="roundcake" name="caketype" value="0" required onclick="CakeChoice('roundcake')">
  <label>Round Cake</label>
</div> 
<br>
<div id="CakeDimensions" >
  <div id="rectangle">
     <label>Cake size (cm)</label><br>
     <input type="number" id="SheetLength" value="0" min="30" max="60" required>
     <label class="form-label required">cm Length</label><br>
     <input type="number" id="SheetWidth" value="0" min="30" max="45" required>
     <label class="form-label required">cm Width</label>
   </div>                 
  <div id="round">
    <label>Cake size</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="RoundRadius" min="15" max="30" required>
    <label class="form-label" "required">cm Radius</label>
  </div> 
</div>
<br>
<div id="cakelayers">
  <label class="form-label required">How many layers?</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="OneLayer" name="CakeLayers" value="1layer" required>
  <label for="OneLayer">One Layer</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="TwoLayers" name="CakeLayers" value="2layers" required>
  <label for="TwoLayers">Two Layers</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="ThreeLayers" name="CakeLayers" value="3layers" required>
  <label for="ThreeLayers">Three Layers</label>
  </div>
<br>
```

Comment: You should disable and toggle the `required` attribute as well as hiding. Otherwise irrelevant values will be sent to the server. The server should sanitize anyway, but no point in sending what is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some minor refactoring to your HTML then removed a bit of replication to your javascript, reducing the dependencies on Ids. This will make it more flexible should you add more options for dimensions or round. I've also illustrated adding the event listeners via javascript.

```js
//Get all the radio buttons in the element with ID caketype and iterate over them
document.querySelectorAll("#caketype input[type=radio]").forEach(function(item) {
  //Add an on click event listener
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //Is Sheet cake chosen from the clicked element
    let isSheetCake = this.value === "sheetcake";
    //Set out disabled AND required attributes based on the above
    //Get the input elements in the fieldset and iterate instead of being bound by id
    document.querySelectorAll("#CakeDimensions input").forEach(function(element) {
      element.disabled = !isSheetCake;
      element.required = isSheetCake;
    });

    //Do the same for round, but invert the logic
    document.querySelectorAll("#round input").forEach(function(element) {
      element.disabled = isSheetCake;
      element.required = !isSheetCake;
    });

    //Bonus: lets set a class to indicate that group is disabled
    //.classList.toggle() ,adds or removes a class, in this case
    //  based on a truthy value
    document.getElementById("CakeDimensions").classList.toggle("disabled", !isSheetCake);
    document.getElementById("round").classList.toggle("disabled", isSheetCake);
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 0;
}

.disabled {
  color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<!-- Ive Given the radio buttond values, which you are going to want if you send this to a server-->
<!-- Also encapsulated the radio button group with a fieldset which is more semantic-->
<!-- Inline Javascript has been removed -->
<!-- Labels have been associated with their form elements with the "for" attribute-->
<fieldset id="caketype">
  <label class="caketype required">Cake Type:</label> <br>
  <input type="radio" id="sheetcake" name="caketype" value="sheetcake" required>
  <label for="sheetcake">Sheet Cake</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="roundcake" name="caketype" value="roundcake" required>
  <label for="roundcake">Round Cake</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="CakeDimensions">
  <label>Cake size (cm)</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="SheetLength" value="0" min="30" max="60" required disabled>
  <label class="form-label required">cm Length</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="SheetWidth" value="0" min="30" max="45" required disabled>
  <label class="form-label required">cm Width</label>
</fieldset>


<fieldset id="round">
  <label>Cake size</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="RoundRadius" min="15" max="30" disabled required>
  <label class="form-label required">cm Radius</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for all of your answers, appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Between [Jon P's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71462236/2813224) and [Dave Pritlove's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71462231/2813224) answers it looks like the basics are already covered. Tihs answer will focus on the following:

- [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation): A programming paradigm in which event bubbling is used to leverage control of an unlimited number of elements by binding an ancestor element to listen for events and delegate which elements react to events and which elements are excluded.
- [HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) interface: Part of the The HTML DOM API, that has terse syntax and unique features:

  - Referencing a form:

    ```
    <form id="UI"></form>
    ```

    ```
    const UI = document.forms.UI 
    /*or*/ 
    const UI = document.forms[0] // the first of one or more forms.
    ```
  - Referencing all form controls<sup>✻</sup> within `UI` with the [`.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) property:

    ```
    <input id='i1' name='IO'> <button name='btn'></button> <input id='i2' name='IO'>
    ```

    ```
    const fC = UI.elements;
    // Reference by #id
    const I1 = fC.i1 // first input by #id
    // Refernce by [name]
    const B = fC.btn // button by [name]
    // HTMLFormsControlCollection of all tags with [name='IO']
    const io = fC.IO // an array-like object of both inputs
    const ioArray = [...io] // convert into an array
    ```
- `[for]` attribute & [`.labels` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/labels) association: Besides the `[for]` attribute & form control `#id` association, there's another type of association we can establish:

  ```
  <label for='A'></label><input id='A'><label for='A'>I'm the 2nd label</label>
  ```

  ```
  const IO = UI.elements;  // collect all of #UI form controls
  const a = IO.A; // reference the input
  const Alabels = a.labels; // collect all label associated to input via [for] to #id
  Alabels[1].textContent; // get the text of the 2nd label
  // result: "I'm the 2nd label"
  ```
- Here's a list of other properties used in the example below:

  - [.checkValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/checkValidity)
  - [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
  - [.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

The example has a step progression:

1. Pick a type
2. Pick a size
3. Choose how many layers

Step 2 is disabled until step 1 is completed.

Step 3 is disabled until the user enters **valid** data in step 2.

<sup>✻form controls: `<button>`, `<fieldset>`, `<input>`, `<object>`, `<output>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`</sup>

```js
const form = document.forms.cake;

form.onchange = cakeStep1;
form.addEventListener('input', cakeStep2);

function cakeStep1(e) {
  const IO = this.elements;
  const picked = e.target;
  const radios = [...IO.type];
  const l = IO.L;
  const w = IO.W;
  const d = IO.D;
  const sSet = IO.sizeSet;

  if (picked.name == 'type') {
    radios.forEach(r => r.labels[0].classList.remove('active'));
    picked.labels[0].classList.add('active')
    sSet.disabled = false;
    if (picked.id == 'sheet') {
      d.disabled = true;
      d.labels[0].classList.add('disabled');
      l.disabled = false;
      l.labels[0].classList.remove('disabled');
      w.disabled = false;
      w.labels[0].classList.remove('disabled');
    } else {
      d.disabled = false;
      d.labels[0].classList.remove('disabled');
      l.disabled = true;
      l.labels[0].classList.add('disabled');
      w.disabled = true;
      w.labels[0].classList.add('disabled');
    }
  }
}

function cakeStep2(e) {
  const IO = this.elements;
  const origin = e.target;
  const l = IO.L;
  const w = IO.W;
  const d = IO.D;
  const lSet = IO.layerSet;
  if (origin.name == 'size') {
    if (IO.sheet.checked && l.checkValidity() == true && w.checkValidity() == true) {
      lSet.disabled = false;
    } else if (IO.round.checked && d.checkValidity() == true) {
      lSet.disabled = false;
    } else {
      lSet.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1.2 'Segoe UI'
}

header {
  margin-bottom: -12px;
  padding: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  width: 18ch;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

[type='radio'] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 1.5ex;
  margin: 0;
}

[type='number'] {
  display: :inline-block;
  width: 10ch;
  float: right;
  text-align: center
}

.active {
  font-weight: 900;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.4
}
```

```html
<form id='cake'>
  <header>
    <h2>Cake Order</h2>
  </header>
  <fieldset name="typeSet">
    <legend>Type</legend>
    <label for='sheet'><input id="sheet" name="type" type="radio" value="sheet"> Sheet Cake</label>
    <label for='round'><input id="round" name="type" value="round" type="radio"> Round Cake</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset name="sizeSet" disabled>
    <legend>Size (cm)</legend>
    <label for='L' class='disabled'>Length: <input id="L" name='size' type="number" min="30" max="60" placeholder='30-60cm' required></label>
    <label for='W' class='disabled'>Width: <input id="W" name='size' type="number" min="30" max="45" placeholder='30-45cm' required></label>
    <label for='D' class='disabled'>Diameter: <input id="D" name='size' type="number" min="15" max="40" placeholder='15-40cm' required></label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset name="layerSet" disabled>
    <legend>Layers</legend>
    <select id='layers' name='layers'>
      <option selected>Number of Layers</option>
      <option value='1'>1 Layer</option>
      <option value='2'>2 Layers</option>
      <option value='3'>3 Layers</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```